# How to use Between in DBFlow

Tags: dbflow

I Want to make Between Query in DBflow,
 like that:

```
Select * From MYTABLE where MYTABLE.NO BETWEEN num1 AND num2
```

But I don't know that how to use `between`.

I usually used query like that

```
public Score find(String No) {
    return SQLite.select()
            .from(Score.class)
            .where(Score_Table.No.eq(No))
            .querySingle();
}
```

Comment: You can write like this Condition.column(columnName).between(value1).and(value2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use between condition like this:

```
public Score find(String No) {
    return SQLite.select()
            .from(Score.class)
            .where(Condition.column(Score_Table.No).between(value1).and(value2))
            .querySingle();
}
```